# Laravel 5.5 PHPUnit does not display descriptions

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

When I run phpunit its show the test is not passed. But It does not tell me why the test is not passing. I have attached two images to describe this.

Here is the result I get:

[image: Failed asserting that actual size 0 matches expected size 1.]

I want something I like this, to help me guide in Test Driven Development:

[image: Failed with a callstack provided]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing different results because you're running into two different categories of failures here:

**1. The code executed, but your assertion failed.**

This happens when PHPUnit gets some assertion that isn't truthy, such as:

```
$this->assertEquals(1, 0);
```

When this happens, PHPUnit only sees that you tried to compare `1` and `0` *and that's everything PHPUnit knows about this*. It can't tell you *why* the code failed, because **you have a business logic error** that isn't detectable by PHP.

**2. Some code you executed raised an error or exception that wasn't caught.**

If you attempt to do something that isn't allowed in PHP (such as referencing a class that doesn't exist), **you have a runtime error**. In these situations, PHP will offer up more information about the error or provide a call-stack with where an exception occurred, resulting in the more detailed message you're seeing.